# BootstrapDialog.Confirm Not Waiting Before Submission

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I'm using Bootstrap Dialog to show the user a nicely styled confirm box before they delete a message. Therefore, I have something like

```
<form onsubmit='return confirmDelMsg()'>
...
</form>
```

The javascript function:

```
function confirmDelMsg() {
    BootstrapDialog.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this message?', function(result) {
         return result;
     });
}
```

The thing is this confirm pop-up appears for a millisecond but doesn't wait for me to click yes or no. Then the message is deleted anyway.

So how can I fix this issue?

This is the library I'm using: Btw, is it called a library or a framework, this BootstrapDialog?

https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/

Do you know of any other libraries such as this one? I know about `bootbox.js` too but it has the same error...

EDIT:

```
function confirmDeleteMsg() {
    return BootstrapDialog.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this message?", function(result) {
       if (result) {
           var deleteMsgForm =  document.getElementById('deleteMsgForm');
           if (typeof(deleteMsgForm) != 'undefined' && deleteMsgForm != null) {
              alert("HERE"); // this here is executing!!!
           }
           deleteMsgForm.submit(); // this is not executing?! why?
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be because confirmDelContact is returning before the confirmation is made. Try with:

```
<form onsubmit='return false;'>
...
</form>
```

And then submit using Javascript or jQuery here:

```
function confirmDelMsg() {
    BootstrapDialog.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this message?', function(result) {
         if (result)
             document.getElementById("deleteMsgForm").submit();
     });
}
```

Attention to this point:

Note that the `submit()` function submits without any `name` attributes. Therefore, be careful since many people do it this way:

```
<form id="deleteMsgForm" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
    <button type="submit" name="deleted" onclick="confirmDelMsg();">Delete Message</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="msgId" value="x" />
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST["deleted"])) {
   // this will NOT work with javascript submit() function!!!
   // because the submit() now doesn't have a name attr
}
// use instead the following:
if (isset($_POST["msgId"])) {
   deleteMsg($_POST["msgId"]);
}
?>
```

Comment: ok. for some reason, I'm not able to submit through javascript!!! I will update my question with the new results.. but thanks for help so far :)

Comment: I've figured it out.. my `input type='submit'` had a `name='deleted'` attribute but with javascript `submit()` function this name attr is removed. And that's why it wasn't deleting because in php I do something like `<?php if (isset($_POST["deleted"]) deleteMsg();?>`... please edit your answer so that I mark it as correct answer.. thank you for your help